# LinearLayoutManager create space between cards

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using a `RecyclerView` to display a list of cards.
It worked well with a `ListView` and an `ArrayListAdapter` but now something strange happens.

When the list is first loaded, the 3 first cards that show up are displayed correctly. But the ones that are not shown have a huge space under each one of them.

It has something to do with the `LayoutManager`, as te Android doc says that it's the entity that manages what to display or not and how to display it.

In my case, I'm using a `LinearLayoutManager`.

Here's some code of my initialization inside my `Fragment`:

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
listAdapter = new EventsListAdapter(events);
recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Here's the `RecyclerView` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/events_list_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally my `CardView` declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/event_row_cardview">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem.

My `CardView` was wrapped inside a `LinearLayout` with the attribute `android:layout_height="match_parent"` so everytime it was rendered it was taking the entire height of the screen.

I fixed it by changing the attribute to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`